# New docs representation in doc2vec Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, doc2vec

I trained doc2vec model in TensorFlow. So now I have embeded vectors for words in dictionary and vectors for the documents.

In the paper

```
"Distributed Representations of Sentences and Documents"
Quoc Le, Tomas Mikolov
```

authors write

> “the inference stage” to get paragraph vectors D for new paragraphs
>   (never seen before) by adding more columns in D and gradient
>   descending on D while holding W,U,b ﬁxed.

I have pretrained model so we have W, U and b as graph variables. Question is how to implement inference of D(new document) efficiently in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

For most neural networks, the output of the network (class for classification problems, number for regression,...) if the value you are interested in. In those cases, inference means running the frozen network on some new data (forward propagation) to compute the desired output.

For those cases, several strategies can be used to deliver quickly the desired output for multiple new data points : scaling horizontally, reduce the complexity of calculation through quantisation of the weights, optimising the freezed graph computation (see https://devblogs.nvidia.com/tensorrt-3-faster-tensorflow-inference/),...

doc2Vec (and word2vec) are different use case is however different : the neural net is used to compute an output (prediction of the next word), but the meaningful and useful data are the weights used in the neural network after training. The inference stage is therefore different : you do not want to get the output of the neural net  to get a vector representation of a new document, you need to train the part of the neural net that provides you the vector representation of your document. Part of the neural net is then frozen (W,U,b).

How can you efficiently compute D (document vector) in Tensorflow :

- Make experiments to define the optimal learning rate (a smaller value might be a better fit for shorter document) as it defines how quick your neural network representation of a document.
- As the other part of the neural net are frozen, you can scale the inference on multiple processes / machines
- Identify the bottle necks : what is currently slow ? model computation ? Text retrieval from disk of from external data source ? Storage of the results ?

Knowing more about your current issues, and the context might help.

Comment: I don't think the question was about scaling the solution. The author was asking how to write the code in the first place... which is also what I'm interesting in.

Comment: Well, if the model is already trained, the implementation of the network is done. Computing inference is just a forward pass (also used during training). My answer relies on the fact that the question asks for an efficient (which I interpret has computationally effective) inference.